# Remote Event Receiver-How to get attachment of list item before updating or adding list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receiver

I want to add restriction to upload only one attachment in list item. I implement attachmentadding event, but if user delete the second attachment, I am not able to get the latest attachment count.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the attachment count using CSOM code below:

```
List targetList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Name");
ListItem oItem = targetList.GetItemById(1);
 
AttachmentCollection oAttachments = oItem.AttachmentFiles;
clientContext.Load(oAttachments);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine(oAttachments.Count)
```

[Get All Attachments From List Item in SharePoint using CSOM](https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/get-all-attachments-from-list-item-in-sharepoint-using-csom)

Comment: Actually I wanted to get the latest attachment count before saving the list item i.e. on ItemAdding or ItemUpdating event

Comment: In ItemAdding/Updating event, add the code logic like above to check attachment count, you may need to change the Item Id with yours

Comment: Yes I tried the same logic in ItemAdding/ItemUpdating event,but no luck this event is also not giving latest count of attachement

Comment: Attachment should be got after ListItem added/updated, as the attachment is based on list item, need to get the list item firstly then attachment.

Comment: Yes right, Do you have any alternative option to put validation on list item before adding in list I wanted to check if attachment is missing and it should not be more than one.